# Does relationism resolve the Sorites paradox?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-language, paradox

The ancient [Sorites](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/sorites-paradox) paradox,

> 1 grain of wheat does not make a heap. If 1 grain doesn’t make a heap,
>   then 2 grains don’t. If 2 grains don’t make a heap, then 3 grains
>   don’t. … If 999,999 grains don’t make a heap, then 1 million grains
>   don’t. Therefore, 1 million grains don’t make a heap.

can be easily applied to all terms with vague boundaries: being tall, old, red, fat and so on. In short, it can be applied to any thing that is subject to change over time or composed by parts.

The term "heap", however, as well as the others, refers to a flexible range, related to the observer and the context of the observation. A person may perceive a group of grains differently from another one, depending on their personal attitudes or the context in which they are located - in the same way as the same amount of money looks scarce to a rich and abundant to a poor one. Even a single observer can perceive a certain number of grains sometimes as a heap and sometimes not, depending on the context. Similarly, it is very likely that, faced with the same situation, similar brains who have undergone a similar education will agree to the use of the word "heap". It's the use of the term "heap" that decrees what a heap is, not vice versa. Although the word occurs on similar circumstances, its use is always specific and must be evaluated one situation at a time, because any identity is precisely defined only through the totality of its relations. The paradox easily applies to any term isolated from a relational context, but it dissolves as soon as it is situated in a relationship ('being taller than', 'less bald than', 'old for', etc): vagueness appears if we consider just a part of the relationships that define something.

Does accepting relationism resolve the Sorites paradox?

Comment: There is no doubt that "heap" is context dependent. But the paradox appears whenever we start piling up grains even if the  context is otherwise fixed. Modus ponens combined with induction simply leads to a contradiction. Vague predicates are those to which induction does not apply.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I don't see how the paradox appears with a fixed contest. i.e I see a pile of grains with n grains and  I call it "heap", or I start piling grains until I decide to call it "heap". Whatever the reasons why I call it "heap" in a determinate context (and time), even if I don't know them (let's suppose they are unconscious), that's an heap relationally defined. Let's say I remove a grain and I decide it's still an heap, there's no paradox here, just a labeling decision, like when I say "enough" while someone pours water in my glass.

Comment: Once you decided that 1 grain is not a heap and adding a grain to not a heap does not turn it into a heap you do not get to decide what to call a heap anymore if you want to stay coherent. The context is moot.

Comment: @Conifold my proposal is that the use of the term "heap" establish what a heap is, not the other way around. The reasons why the label is or is not applied are to be found in the particular cases, and have not to be coherent; the context is unknown, not moot.

Comment: The problem exploited in the paradox is that we do not just decide on the use of a word one situation at a time, we want that use at a minimum to satisfy some logical constraints. So if I understand you correctly your proposal is either moot or incoherent.

Comment: @Conifold my idea is that the paradox shows that there are not intrinsic concepts and that we can properly use a word one situation at a time.

Comment: It is not about intrinsic concepts but about usefulness. If "heap" is just a vocalization made in reaction to a situation with no strings attached it is not useful for communication with others, nor even as a marker to the person vocalizing. It is just some kind of emotional relief, like moan from pain. We might as well dispense with the word and just moan, otherwise some stability of use is needed. If this is the price of "solving" the paradox it is better to just live with it, besides, far more attractive approaches are available.

Comment: @conifold no price at all, communication keeps working. It is very likely that, faced with the same situation, similar brains who have undergone a similar education will agree to the use of the word "heap", even if their use is slightly different each time, depending on the context. I edited the question with my replies to your observations, thank you, I hope it will be useful for other readers.

Comment: "It is very likely" is not good enough, communication has to be reliable. The way it is achieved is by coordinating use conventionally: if there is indeed good overlap in individual uses then it is spelled out and made into a uniform convention. The paradox arises in this context because no such rule is consistent with both modus ponens and induction. Your proposal is to develop no convention at all. Ok, but this is a "solution" that has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: @Conifold I disagree, "It is very likely" is enough for our language to work, since we manage to communicate but misunderstandings and adjustments always happen. The language you are speaking about looks more like math.

Comment: Actually, you just agreed that what you are proposing is irrelevant to the paradox, think it over.

Comment: @Conifold I knew you would say that :) I don't, but my analogy was misleading. I think that to formalize the sorite is a mistake _exactly_ because of what I said. "Heap" is not reducible to a mathematical concept, since we should reduce it to a number of grains, and this is not what an heap is. We are talking about heaps, where "it is very likely" is enough, since we manage to communicate although misunderstandings and adjustments happen. We just can't define the convention because it's too complex, being partially related to every occurrence of "heap".

Comment: Whether formalizing a sorite is a mistake or not is moot. It may be a mistake to construct perpetuum mobiles but the point is to figure out why they do not work. That informal concepts are not mathematically precise is a banality. The question is how close one can get and the, surprising, answer in this case is that not too close. The problem is not with complexity, there is no complexity here, but with a clash of intuitions underlying informal language use. And since we know it is there there is nothing really left to "resolve".

Comment: @conifold I don’t think that informal concept can’t be mathematically precise. Complex because it’s precise but hard to tell: Let’s say that ‘heap’ indicate the number from x to y of grains in the use that makes,had made and will made every being in every time and universe.

Comment: If a concept is mathematicallly precise it is no longer informal. "from x to y of grains in the use that makes,had made and will made every being in every time and universe"??? No idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To introduce relationism is an interesting angle but I don't think it punctures the paradox. The fact that you and I might disagree on whether X, a pile of beans, constitutes a heap can readily be conceded but that can still leave us with individual sorites problems.

Regardless of what you think - out of relation to it - I may have my own sorites problem because in fact I might not be able to decide whether X is a heap. And you - out of all relation to me or anyone else - might not be able to decide whether Y is a heap.

If the question whether X constitutes a heap is to be determined 'only through the totality of its relations with others', any such totality is impossible to serve as a criterion or metric. Imagine enumerating and specifying the totality of *anything's* relations to others. It's a theoretically possible but practically unreal possibility - and sorites problem are all too practical.

But an intriguing line of approach.

Comment: Thank you for your interesting answer! I don’t think we can have ‘private’ sorites, since language is a common praxis and I would simply use the rules I learned to judge what an heap is. Moreover, there could be a part of my mind in relation to another one that label ideas and words. I agree that is practically impossibile to specify the totality of the relations, but I disagree  that Sorite is just a practical issue. When it’s practical, it’s a problem but not a paradox, since it’s always related to the subjective use of words and ideas (I.e when a fetus is a person)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't mean 'private' and certainly not 'logically private' sorites. I meant that even within a common community and a shared language we can and do have individual problems about e.g. what counts as a heap. I liked your question and am glad that you found my answer interesting. Best - Geoffrey